# How do I make a function in Javascript move with my mouse while the mouse is on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a small game in which the player must find a character that I planted somewhere within a picture. I made it so that this picture is the background image of a canvas element. Then I drew a black rectangle that covered the entirety of the canvas so that the background image was not visible. Lastly, I made a function called clearCircle that clears a circular area of the black rectangle so that the background image is only visible within that area.

Ultimately, I would really like to have the coordinates of the clearCircle function to change to where ever the mouse is located on the canvas and to constantly move with the mouse. When working properly, this should create an almost flashlight-in-the-dark effect when the mouse is on the canvas.

*I have an event listener that incorporates "mousemove" although it does not appear to work with the other code I have written. I am relatively new to programming so it is very likely that other pieces of my code are flawed as well.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<title>Where's Lumpy Space Princess?</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Canvas Background through CSS</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
a {
color: white;
}
.footer { 
        text-align:center;
        position:fixed; 
        bottom: 0px; 
        } 
canvas { background:url(cave.gif) }
  body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1> Where's Lumpy Space Princess?</h1>
<p>"Oh my glob you guys, I'm lost!"</p>
<img src="lspsay.gif">
<h2> Instructions:</h2>
<h3> L.S.P. is lost in the dark cave and can't find her way out!               Fortunately, you can guide her with your flashlight!<br>
But first, you have to find her.<br>
When you find her, click on the link at the bottom of the page to move on. </h3>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="750">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
 </canvas>
<script>
var canvas
var rect
canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
rect=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

function getCoords(ev){

  var mx;

  var my;

   mx = ev.clientX-rect.left;

   my = ev.clientY-rect.top;

   return [mx,my]; }

 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", getCoords, false);



 var cover = document.getElementById("canvas"), context =     cover.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0,0,1000,750);


function clearCircle(context,x,y,radius) {
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
  context.clip();
  context.clearRect(x-radius,y-radius,radius*2,radius*2);
  context.restore();
 }
  while (true); {
  getCoords();
  clearCircle(context,clientX-rect,clientY-rect,/*radius=*/60);
}


</script>
<br>
<p> Image Source: http://s3.amazonaws.com/placester-    wordpress/blogs.dir/589/files/2012/08/caveman-cave-091746.jpg<p>
<br>
<a href="myfinalproject1.html">Click Here to Move On</a>
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="cave.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: subscribe to the onmousemove event of the canvas!

Answer (score 0):

[Mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) will give you the mouse coordinates when the user has the mouse over the canvas.

Comment: I changed my event listener to this: canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", clearCircle, false);                          However, this still doesn't make the clearCircle function move the way I would like it to. Is there any code I should add so that the clearCircle function will move with the mouse on the canvas?